# Why do my LED lights turn on for split second when I turn ceiling fan on/off

Tags: electrical

when i turn on/off fan, i see my LED lights are on for a split second. is it because of bad wiring? my issue is very similar 
[exact same issue which i found on other post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/94045/why-do-ceiling-lights-turn-on-when-i-turn-ceiling-fan-off/101943)

any idea why they are turn on for split second? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

LEDs need ***very**** little power compared to other kinds of lights. A weak induced current from an adjacent circuit being turned on or off could well be enough to get a momentary flash from them. If this is the only problem you're seeing, I recommend just ignoring it.

Comment: makes sense. i don't see any other problem. i will ignore it then. thank you.